# Ubuntu Router: Can't ping between two NICs

Tags: networking, server, internet, firewall, router

I'm quite new to networking and I'm simply trying to set up a robust router and firewall with my barebone Ubuntu 20.04 server.
Consider the following setup of the NICs:

`enp3s0`:
IP: 192.168.1.23
Connected to a router that connects to WAN (router's IP 192.168.1.5)

`enp4s0`:
IP: 192.168.1.24
Connected to my internal network switch to allow, giving access to all the other devices in my network

I've followed all the steps required to make my server a router and route all the packets from my local network devices to the router and then to the WAN.
Note: the reason why I've settled for making my server into a router while already having a router is that the router provided to me belongs to my ISP and I'm not allowed to change any configs in that router or do anything with it whatsoever. It doesn't even have a firewall (long story).

Ping results:
`ping -I enp4s0 192.168.1.23`
`PING 192.168.1.23 (192.168.1.23) from 192.168.1.24 enp4s0: 56(84) bytes of data.`
And it stucks right here...

`ping -I enp3s0 192.168.1.24`
`PING 192.168.1.24 (192.168.1.24) from 192.168.1.23 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.`
Like the above ping, this ping also stucks here...

My netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.23/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.5
      nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.23]
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.24/24
      nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.23]
  version: 2
```

Route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
```

Comment: have you modified any of the settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` yet? (and have you really got both your "internal" and "external" networks set to the same IP address range?)

Comment: @jad Yes, I've uncommented the packet forwarding rule:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
And yes, the internal and external networks have the same IP address range and subnet mask. I recently read that it's not advised, but don't have enough knowledge on what else to do...

Comment: Please note that there is no gateway listed at all in `route -n` Please add `gateway4: 192.168.1.5` to the enp4s0 stanza and follow with: `sudo netplan generate && sudo netplan apply` and see if there is any improvement. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: is it possible to change one of the interfaces to `192.168.2.0/24` so that they can route?

Comment: @chili555 `route -n` produces the following results:
`Kernel IP routing table`<br>
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface`<br>
`0.0.0.0         192.168.1.5     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0`<br>
`10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0`<br>
`172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0`<br>
`192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0`<br>
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0

Comment: If I do change one of the interfaces to a different subnet, then I'd have to change the IP for all my devices and I have around 10 devices connected with static IP, which will be painful. Any other way to solve this? @jad

Comment: Leaving the inside subnet and the outside subnet the same makes it too easy to bypass your firewall / router defeating the purpose of it.

Comment: Take down your VPN and see if anything changes.

Comment: For testing purposes, I tried changing the `enp4s0` IP to `192.168.2.1/24` and still didn't see any results. Is there something I'm missing?
Let's say I wanna make them into two subnets, how should I structure my network?

Comment: @heynnema Did `systemctl stop openvpn` and then pinged.. No improvement.

Comment: you won't be able to ping the IP address from the wrong interface.  that isn't how it works. ... I'll add an answer so that I can add more code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `enp4s0` is your "private" network:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.23/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.5
      nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.23]
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.1/24
  version: 2
```

you'll then need to configure a computer on your private network to be `192.168.2.x` in order to test pinging of the 192.168.1.23 IP address.

you will have trouble with the 192.168.1.0 network pinging the 192.168.2.0 network, unless you can teach the 192.168.1.0 network of the existence of the 192.168.2.0 network (you might be lucky with auto-discovery, but in the past I have had mixed success with it)

you might find it easier to set up NAT on your linux router, so that all requests to the 192.168.1.0 network come from the 192.168.1.23 IP address.

as per: [How_to_set_up_a_NAT_router_on_a_Linux-based_computer](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_NAT_router_on_a_Linux-based_computer) :

```
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
```

(hopefully I've got the enpsx's the right way around)